# How to query a database table which store the datetime values as biginit

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a third party SQL Server database, and inside the following table they store the RESPONSETIME as bigint as follows:

[image]

Now I want to get the records which have their RESPONSETIME between 22-March till 31-March, something as follow:

```
where srm.RESPONSETIME >= '2021-03-22 00:00:00' and srm.RESPONSETIME <= '2021-03-31 23:59:59'
```

Currently when I run the above I will get this error:

> Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

So is there a way to have things working well for me?

Thanks

Now the 3rd party provide this function to convert the long into the related data:-

```
USE [Servicedesk]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[longtodate]    Script Date: 03/29/2021 20:15:30 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[longtodate](@utc BIGINT)
RETURNS DATETIME
AS 
BEGIN
RETURN DATEADD(MILLISECOND, @utc % 1000, DATEADD(SECOND, @utc / 1000, '19700101'))
END
```

But I am not sure how I can add this function to my SQL?

Comment: Please *don't* use images for code, data or errors. Use formatted text. A number is not a date, so you can't compare them that way. You have to understand how that number translates to a date, and then translate it in order to compare.

Comment: @DaleK yes agree but my main SQL is written in text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than converting the `responsetime` to a date to compare, you should do the reverse and convert your date to the same format. This will allow SQL Server to seek directly to the relevant rows using a suitable index on ResponseTime.

Assuming the date is `@yourdate` and assuming the integer value is milliseconds since 01/01/1970 then the following should hopefully work

```
Select * from
survey_response_main
where responsetime = cast(Datediff(s, '19700101', @yourdate) as bigint)*1000
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 (one way of measuring the Unix epoch).  You can test this by checking the value of:

```
select dateadd(second, responsetime / 1000, '1970-01-01')
```

Comment: but how i can use this inside the where?

Comment: @johnGu . . . Yes, assuming that it produces reasonable values.  There are a zillion different epochs (that is, relative times with different 0 time points), so this is a reasonable guess.

Comment: @johnGu for a sargeable query you'd be better off converting your dates to an equivalent number, then you are just comparing numbers.

Comment: @DaleK can you advice more on this? i am running this sql using dapper inside my c# console application.. so i can define the variables as needed